# SASS with Node.js on AWS - compiling stylesheets

Tags: css, node.js, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm developing an app that is deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with a Node.js backend. For styles I use SASS. SASS files are version controlled with Git, but compiled CSS files are not. However, when using `eb deploy`, only the SASS files are sent to Elastic Beanstalk.

What is the best way to make sure all the SASS files are compiled to CSS and sent to EB without having to include them in Git?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html

```
option_settings:
 - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs
   option_name: NodeCommand
   value: "gulp build && npm start"
```

Look at **gulp build**, just replace it with your command that compiles your assets